# Fit CDF with 2 Gaussian using LeastSq

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, gaussian, least-squares, cdf

I am trying to fit empirical CDF plot to two Gaussian cdf as it seems that it has two peaks, but it does not work. I fit the curve with **leastsq** from **scipy.optimize** and **erf** function from **scipy.special**. The fitting only gives constant line at a value of 2. I am not sure in which part of the code that I make mistake. Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks!

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([ 90.64115156,  90.85690063,  91.07264971,  91.28839878,
        91.50414786,  91.71989693,  91.93564601,  92.15139508,
        92.36714415,  92.58289323,  92.7986423 ,  93.01439138,
        93.23014045,  93.44588953,  93.6616386 ,  93.87738768,
        94.09313675,  94.30888582,  94.5246349 ,  94.74038397,
        94.95613305,  95.17188212,  95.3876312 ,  95.60338027,
        95.81912935,  96.03487842,  96.2506275 ,  96.46637657,
        96.68212564,  96.89787472,  97.11362379,  97.32937287,
        97.54512194,  97.76087102,  97.97662009,  98.19236917,
        98.40811824,  98.62386731,  98.83961639,  99.05536546,
        99.27111454,  99.48686361,  99.70261269,  99.91836176,
       100.13411084, 100.34985991, 100.56560899, 100.78135806,
       100.99710713, 101.21285621])
y = np.array([3.33333333e-04, 3.33333333e-04, 3.33333333e-04, 1.00000000e-03,
       1.33333333e-03, 3.33333333e-03, 6.66666667e-03, 1.30000000e-02,
       2.36666667e-02, 3.40000000e-02, 5.13333333e-02, 7.36666667e-02,
       1.01666667e-01, 1.38666667e-01, 2.14000000e-01, 3.31000000e-01,
       4.49666667e-01, 5.50000000e-01, 6.09000000e-01, 6.36000000e-01,
       6.47000000e-01, 6.54666667e-01, 6.61000000e-01, 6.67000000e-01,
       6.76333333e-01, 6.84000000e-01, 6.95666667e-01, 7.10000000e-01,
       7.27666667e-01, 7.50666667e-01, 7.75333333e-01, 7.93333333e-01,
       8.11333333e-01, 8.31333333e-01, 8.56333333e-01, 8.81333333e-01,
       9.00666667e-01, 9.22666667e-01, 9.37666667e-01, 9.47333333e-01,
       9.59000000e-01, 9.70333333e-01, 9.77333333e-01, 9.83333333e-01,
       9.90333333e-01, 9.93666667e-01, 9.96333333e-01, 9.99000000e-01,
       9.99666667e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
plt.plot(a,b,'r.')

# Fitting with 2 Gaussian
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def two_gaussian_cdf(params, x):
    (mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2) = params
    model = 0.5*(1 + erf( (x-mu1)/(sigma1*np.sqrt(2)) )) +\
            0.5*(1 + erf( (x-mu2)/(sigma2*np.sqrt(2)) ))
    return model

def residual_two_gaussian_cdf(params, x, y):
    model = double_gaussian(params, x)
    return model - y

params = [5.,2.,1.,2.]
out = leastsq(residual_two_gaussian_cdf,params,args=(x,y))
double_gaussian(out[0],x)
plt.plot(x,two_gaussian_cdf(out[0],x))
```

which return to this plot

[image]

Comment: at least part of the problem is the initial parameter values. Try "params = [100.,2.,100.,2.]" and it is somewhat more realistic. I don't know if there are other problems, but the original values in your posting are certainly giving you trouble. I used the scipy module scipy.optimize.differential_evolution to make a search for initial parameters, these are round numbers for the results I received from that module.

Comment: oh yeah. I just realize the x-axis values are so large that parameters at the order of 1 do not work well. I tried the values you gave and it works. Nice to know the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution module. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesPhillips, could you tell me how to run the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution module for getting the estimation?

Comment: See my answer below. I cannot format code in the comments, and so provided the code in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find `lmfit` (see http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) to be a useful alternative to `leastsq` here as it provides a higher-level interface to optimization and curve fitting (though still based on `scipy.optimize.leastsq`).  With lmfit, your example might look like this (cutting out the definition of `x` and `y` data):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

# define the basic model.  I included an amplitude parameter
def gaussian_cdf(x, amp, mu, sigma):
    return (amp/2.0)*(1 + erf( (x-mu)/(sigma*np.sqrt(2))))

# create a model that is the sum of two gaussian_cdfs
# note that a prefix names each component and will be
# applied to the parameter names for each model component
model = Model(gaussian_cdf, prefix='g1_') + Model(gaussian_cdf, prefix='g2_')

# make a parameters object -- a dict with parameter names
# taken from the arguments of your model function and prefix
params = model.make_params(g1_amp=0.50, g1_mu=94, g1_sigma=1,
                           g2_amp=0.50, g2_mu=98, g2_sigma=1.)

# you can apply bounds to any parameter
#params['g1_sigma'].min = 0   # sigma must be > 0!

# you may want to fix the amplitudes to 0.5:
#params['g1_amp'].vary = False
#params['g2_amp'].vary = False

# run the fit
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# print results
print(result.fit_report())

# plot results, including individual components
comps = result.eval_components(result.params, x=x)

plt.plot(x, y,'r.', label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'k-', label='fit')
plt.plot(x, comps['g1_'], 'b--', label='g1_')
plt.plot(x, comps['g2_'], 'g--', label='g2_')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This prints out a report of

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(gaussian_cdf, prefix='g1_') + Model(gaussian_cdf, prefix='g2_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 66
    # data points      = 50
    # variables        = 6
    chi-square         = 0.00626332
    reduced chi-square = 1.4235e-04
    Akaike info crit   = -437.253376
    Bayesian info crit = -425.781238
[[Variables]]
    g1_amp:    0.65818908 +/- 0.00851338 (1.29%) (init = 0.5)
    g1_mu:     93.8438526 +/- 0.01623273 (0.02%) (init = 94)
    g1_sigma:  0.54362156 +/- 0.02021614 (3.72%) (init = 1)
    g2_amp:    0.34058664 +/- 0.01153346 (3.39%) (init = 0.5)
    g2_mu:     97.7056728 +/- 0.06408910 (0.07%) (init = 98)
    g2_sigma:  1.24891832 +/- 0.09204020 (7.37%) (init = 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(g1_amp, g2_amp)     = -0.892
    C(g2_amp, g2_sigma)   =  0.848
    C(g1_amp, g2_sigma)   = -0.744
    C(g1_amp, g1_mu)      =  0.692
    C(g1_amp, g2_mu)      =  0.662
    C(g1_mu, g2_amp)      = -0.607
    C(g1_amp, g1_sigma)   =  0.571
```

and a plot like this:

[image]
This fit is not perfect, but it should get you started.

Comment: This is a great answer! I will surely look into lmfit. The report provides detail information of the fitting. Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution module to generate initial parameter estimates for curve fitting. I have coded the sum of squared errors as the target for the genetic algorithm as shown below. This scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires parameter bounds within which to search. In this case, the parameter bounds are automatically derived from the data so that there is no need to provide them manually in the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings

from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
from scipy.special import erf


# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def two_gaussian_cdf(x, mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2):
    model = 0.5*(1 + erf( (x-mu1)/(sigma1*np.sqrt(2)) )) +\
            0.5*(1 + erf( (x-mu2)/(sigma2*np.sqrt(2)) ))
    return model


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    return np.sum((yData - two_gaussian_cdf(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # data min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # parameter bounds for mu1
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # parameter bounds for sigma1
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # parameter bounds for mu2
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # parameter bounds for sigma2

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x


xData = np.array([ 90.64115156,  90.85690063,  91.07264971,  91.28839878,
        91.50414786,  91.71989693,  91.93564601,  92.15139508,
        92.36714415,  92.58289323,  92.7986423 ,  93.01439138,
        93.23014045,  93.44588953,  93.6616386 ,  93.87738768,
        94.09313675,  94.30888582,  94.5246349 ,  94.74038397,
        94.95613305,  95.17188212,  95.3876312 ,  95.60338027,
        95.81912935,  96.03487842,  96.2506275 ,  96.46637657,
        96.68212564,  96.89787472,  97.11362379,  97.32937287,
        97.54512194,  97.76087102,  97.97662009,  98.19236917,
        98.40811824,  98.62386731,  98.83961639,  99.05536546,
        99.27111454,  99.48686361,  99.70261269,  99.91836176,
       100.13411084, 100.34985991, 100.56560899, 100.78135806,
       100.99710713, 101.21285621])
yData = np.array([3.33333333e-04, 3.33333333e-04, 3.33333333e-04, 1.00000000e-03,
       1.33333333e-03, 3.33333333e-03, 6.66666667e-03, 1.30000000e-02,
       2.36666667e-02, 3.40000000e-02, 5.13333333e-02, 7.36666667e-02,
       1.01666667e-01, 1.38666667e-01, 2.14000000e-01, 3.31000000e-01,
       4.49666667e-01, 5.50000000e-01, 6.09000000e-01, 6.36000000e-01,
       6.47000000e-01, 6.54666667e-01, 6.61000000e-01, 6.67000000e-01,
       6.76333333e-01, 6.84000000e-01, 6.95666667e-01, 7.10000000e-01,
       7.27666667e-01, 7.50666667e-01, 7.75333333e-01, 7.93333333e-01,
       8.11333333e-01, 8.31333333e-01, 8.56333333e-01, 8.81333333e-01,
       9.00666667e-01, 9.22666667e-01, 9.37666667e-01, 9.47333333e-01,
       9.59000000e-01, 9.70333333e-01, 9.77333333e-01, 9.83333333e-01,
       9.90333333e-01, 9.93666667e-01, 9.96333333e-01, 9.99000000e-01,
       9.99666667e-01, 1.00000000e+00])

# generate initial parameter values
initialParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the data
fittedParameters, niepewnosci = curve_fit(two_gaussian_cdf, xData, yData, initialParameters)

# create values for display of fitted peak function
mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2 = fittedParameters
y_fit = two_gaussian_cdf(xData, mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2)

plt.plot(xData, yData) # plot the raw data
plt.plot(xData, y_fit) # plot the equation using the fitted parameters
plt.show()

print(fittedParameters)
```

Comment: Thank you for writing the explanation. I understand now we need to set the objective function to be the difference between model and actual data. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a large dataset you can generate initial parameter estimates on a representative subset of the data and have much better performance as compared to using the entire dataset.  I use this technique in my open source fitting library.

Comment: I just take a look at your library. It's a massive library of curve fitting. It is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. You might be interested to look over the online curve fitting and surface fitting web application powered by this library, the URL is http://zunzun.com - it is also open source. The library itself comes with many examples, including parallel processing for higher performance.